# F# list filter opposite of equal

Tags: list, f#

Whats the opposite of this in F#

```
let x = [1 .. 5] |> List.filter(fun x -> x = 4)
```

I have tried

```
let x = [1 .. 5] |> List.filter(fun x -> x != 4)

let x = [1 .. 5] |> List.filter(fun x -> x not 4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the inequality function `<>`:

```
let x = [1 .. 5] |> List.filter(fun x -> x <> 4)
val x : int list = [1; 2; 3; 5]
```